# Python: Sort lists in lists numerically

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list like this one:

```
list1 = [['art_25', 'title', 'author'], ['art_12', 'title', 'author'], ['art_4', 'title', 'author']]
```

How can I sort this list s.t. the output equals

```
[['art_4', 'title', 'author'], ['art_12' ...], ['art_25', ...]] ?
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with the `key` parameter. You can make a `lambda` expression that splits on the `'_'` character, turns it into an `int` then sorts by that value.

```
list1 = [['art_25', 'title', 'author'],
         ['art_12', 'title', 'author'],
         ['art_4', 'title', 'author']]

>>> sorted(list1, key=lambda i: int(i[0].split('_')[1]))
[['art_4', 'title', 'author'],
 ['art_12', 'title', 'author'],
 ['art_25', 'title', 'author']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. What can I do if some articles are named like: '2014_en_12', '2014_en_6' etc. ?